# How to combine output from awk and pipe into htop?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
$ ps -ef | grep python | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
9825
4470
4619

$ htop -p 9825,4470,4619
```

For now, I have to make two separate commands in order to watch all python processes within `htop`. Is there a way that I can pipe all the results from `awk` and feed them into `htop`?

Comment: xargs to join the lines?

Comment: You could comma delimit the output from `awk`, pipe to `xargs` and then use that in the `htop` command (I think, totally not tested, probably needs tweaking): `ps -ef | grep python | awk -F' ' 'BEGIN{ORS=","}{print $2}' | xargs -I {} htop -p {}`

Comment: `$ htop -p $(ps -ef | grep python | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | paste -sd "," -)`

Comment: @q0987 That's prettier than xargs! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `pgrep` (you probably do):

```
htop -p $(pgrep python | paste -sd,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid `grep` and use only `awk` using something like:

```
ps -ef | awk '/[p]ython/{print $2}'
```

Then you could use:

```
htop -p $(ps -ef | awk -v ORS=, '/[p]ython/{print $2}')
```

Notice the `[]` around the `p`, this is a nice trick to avoid printing the second command itself:

```
 ps -ef | awk '/[p]ython/{print $2}'
     |         |
  cmd 1       cmd 2
```

it works because `awk` will translate the regex `[p]` to say something like "match characters from  `[p]` in this case, `p` only, followed by `ython`:

```
[p]ython != python
```